# Unable to determine workspace

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-power-tools

In powershell when I run

`Get-TfsItemHistory . -Recurse -Version C13855~C14103`

I get error `Unable to determine the source control server.`

If I were running tfpt.exe I could simply do `tf workspaces /s:serverUrl`.

How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running these 4 commands in PS fixed the issue

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
 $tfsServerString = "http://server:8080/tfs/optionalName"
 $tfs = get-tfsserver $tfsServerString
 Get-TfsItemHistory $/TeamProjectName -Recurse -Version C13855~C14103 -Server $tfs | fl Comment,ChangesetId,CreationDate,Committer
```

This issue is specific to x64 windows.

Comment: Operative for us 'This issue is specific to x64'.  When we ran the same powerhsell TFS commands from the 'Windows Powershell (x86)' everything succeeded.  This was all either due to TFS 2013 or the user being in a parent domain of the domain that TFS is in.